# Не добавляет в iframe текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

Не могу понять в чем причина. Вот код, самый элементарный. При выводе (и через сервер, и без) не видит ни текста "Что-то уже написано", ни то, что хочу добавить

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#addcols" ).click(function(){ 
       $("iframe#frm").contents().append("ffff");

 });

});
    </script> 
</head>
<body>     
<input type="submit" id="addcols" />
<iframe id="frm"> Что-то уже написано
</iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что содержимое тега `iframe` отображается только тогда, когда этот тег не поддерживается. Т. е. никогда для всех браузеров, о которых сейчас может идти речь.

Comment: так как мне тогда исправить чтобы заработало?

Comment: @Костя, заменить `iframe` на `div`?

Comment: глупости жизни, что уж. Почему то решил через iframe работать. теперь все работает

Comment: @Костя, ответ прими (нажми зелёную галочку слева).